# How do I extract text from a string when the position changes? (Visual Basic)

Tags: string, crystal-reports, report

I have a list of strings where there is a job number that I wish to extract. The formatting and position of this number is always different.

E.G. (Job number in bold).

- JC Co#: 1 Contact: **20202.** Month: Jan 1 2012 12:00AM
- JC Co#: 1 Contact: **321.** Month: Jan 1 2012 12:00AM
- JC Co#: 1 Contact: **20093.** Month: Jan 1 2012 12:00AM
- JC Co#: 1 Job: **OOSJ.** Month: Jan 1 2012 12:00AM
- JC Co#: 1 Job: **O333J.** Month: Jan 1 2012 12:00AM
- JC Co#: 1 Job: **323J.** ACO: Jan 1 2012 12:00AM

Comment: What flavor of VB? VBA, VB6, VBScript, VB.NET? What does Crystal Reports have to do with your question? (Or Basic, which is *not* VB, or Report.) Please use specific tags that are relevant to your question. You can [edit] to include the proper ones and remove those that aren't applicable - you might want to fix the typo in the subject while you're at it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the examples given, I suggest the strategy of:

1. Find the second colon
2. Find the first full stop / period after the second colon
3. Select the text between these two

I don't have access to (any variation of) VB at the moment but in C# it would look something like:

```
var text = "JC Co#: 1 Job: OOSJ. Month: Jan 1 2012 12:00AM";
var firstColonPosition = text.IndexOf(":");
var secondColonPosition = text.IndexOf(":", firstColonPosition + 1);
var firstPeriodPosition = text.IndexOf(".", secondColonPosition);
var jobNumberText = text.Substring(secondColonPosition + 1, firstPeriodPosition - secondColonPosition - 1);
```

I'm not sure about the spacing so you'll probably want to trim the result.

Answer (score 0):

Use can use substr with instr.
like your field value is 
`asdfg - itsnoteasy - whattod`

and you don't need - `whattodo` from the field 
`substr(field,0, instr(field,'-',1,2)-1)`

see link,

http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/Forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=17842
http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/Forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=10231